# Mongo, Express vs mySQL

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

im currently in the face of considering what to use for building a piece of software - The system needs to handle complexity like: 
- User Management (ex: Trainer Login - Client login)

Different dashboards (Depending on user profile)

Workout Builder (Trainer must be able to create workout programs and send(email) and attach (Client can see workout program in system) the program to a client)

Diet Plans (much like the above)

Workout Library

Booking/Calendar (Client should be able to book a trainer)

Training Logs etc...

---

As you can see, there would be alot of relations/bindings etc, and personlization (Dashboards) etc... I think you get the idea :) - However, im a Frontend Developer, I do have php experience and mySQL (However a long time ago) - So the question is... Is this system possible to build completely with  ex: Angular, Express, Mongo and Node - Or would I have to depend on a database system like mySQL and use ex: PHP for the system ?

Thx in advance for any answers :)

Comment: Mongo(DB) is a database system and Node let you run javascript server side. Simply said Mongo could replace MySQL and Node could replace PHP. It's also worth mentioning Node can just as easily use MySQL, and you can use Mongo in PHP. So you're not really limited to any set of tools here. Angular won't care what you run server side so you should choose the technology you're most confident with. Or if this is for fun/learning - choose whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to build on pure JavaScript stack like MEAN: MongoDB, Angular, Express, Node.js

Everything that MySQL does, MongoDB can do also.  The question is only in proper database design and performance for specific use cases.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if your hands on experience with PHP and MySQL is good enough you should go ahead and deploy your application with PHP and MySQL with MongoDB as an additional database.

I understand that MEAN stack can power up your complete app, but the development time would be longer, and for what I have felt while using MongoDB over petabytes of data is that MongoDB is amazingly great for storing complex data in a flat architecture in massive size. But just like all databases, even MongoDB has certain constraints.

You should go ahead with MySQL for your usual Login credentials and minor activities, for storing Diet Plans, Workout Libraries use MongoDB. Because that gives you a flexibility of the varying document structure and high availability. Over the time you will find MongoDB easier to work upon than MySQL.

Using MEAN Stack is great. But, now I prefer to use a mixed architecture of MySQL, MongoDB, and PostGres. If you are going to use any framework it would probably have ACL in it or available as an add-on, and that could help you with building permissions and roles of users.

Also, if you are using MongoDB, make sure you code according to the engine MMAP or WiredTiger, I had to do a major recoding because of the storage engine changes. Just a heads up!